# How to customize a lazy-loaded variable?

Tags: spacemacs, start-up, customization, eval-after-load

In Spacemacs, how can I customize a variable used in a layer that's loaded lazily?

Specifically, I'm trying to use Zathura and Synctex with Spacemacs' Latex layer. I have the following code in my `dotspacemacs/user-config`.

```
(with-eval-after-load "tex"
  '(progn
     (add-to-list 'TeX-view-program-list
                  '("Zathura"
                    ("zathura "
                     (mode-io-correlate " --synctex-forward %n:0:%b   -x \"emacsclient +%{line} %{input}\" ")
                     " %o")
                    "zathura"))
     (add-to-list 'TeX-view-program-selection
                  '(output-pdf "Zathura"))
     (TeX-PDF-mode 1)
     ))
```

My intent is to mutate the variables `TeX-view-program-list` and `TeX-view-program-selection` after the Latex layer is loaded since before that the variables are free, but this code doesn't seem to be working. Note that if I explicitly evaluate those two `add-to-list` expressions after opening a `.tex` file, they have their intended effect and Spacemacs defaults to viewing with Zathura.

Does anyone know if there's a canonical way to customize the variables used in the Emacs modes provided by Spacemacs layers?

Comment: You can do `M-x customize-variable RET TeX-view-program-list RET`. See [Customization](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Customization.html#Customization) in the Emacs manual.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Replace `'(progn ...)` with `(progn ...)`

By putting the quote there you are specifically telling emacs NOT to evaluate the code in your `progn`. In fact you don't need progn at all. It looks like you are trying to treat `with-eval-after-load` like `eval-after-load`. Note the signature differences:

> (with-eval-after-load FILE &rest BODY)

vs

> (eval-after-load FILE FORM)

This is how it should be written:

```lisp
(with-eval-after-load "tex"
  (add-to-list 'TeX-view-program-list
               '("Zathura"
                 ("zathura "
                  (mode-io-correlate " --synctex-forward %n:0:%b   -x \"emacsclient +%{line} %{input}\" ")
                  " %o")
                 "zathura"))
  (add-to-list 'TeX-view-program-selection
               '(output-pdf "Zathura"))
  (TeX-PDF-mode 1))
```

Also note that nothing here is specific to Spacemacs, this is the same for any autoloaded Emacs package.

Comment: Thanks, that did it and thanks for the explanation. I get it now.